# putting a matplotlib graph into wxpython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have this code which creates an interactive scatter graph:

```
if 1: # picking on a scatter plot (matplotlib.collections.RegularPolyCollection)

x, y, c, s = rand(4, 100)
def onpick3(event):
    ind = event.ind
    print('onpick3 scatter:', ind, np.take(x, ind), np.take(y, ind))

fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
col = ax1.scatter(x, y, 100*s, c, picker=True)
#fig.savefig('pscoll.eps')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
```

What I want to do is integrate this graph into wxPython

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You may find this blog post helpful: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to put the figure inside a wxPanel. See [here for a good example](http://dafx.org/an-easy-to-use-python-plotting-tool-with-wxpython-and-matplotlib/).

```
class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes1 = self.figure.add_subplot(211)
        self.axes2 = self.figure.add_subplot(212)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()
        self.figure.tight_layout()
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onMotion)

    def onMotion(self, event):
        if event.inaxes:
            xpos = event.xdata
            print(' %0.1f' % (xpos))
```